# jquery mobile site not formatting on android device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am using an example from www3schools to see how to create an application on an android device;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-
    1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    var _hmt = _hmt || [];
    (function() {
    var hm = document.createElement("script");
    hm.src = "//hm.baidu.com/hm.js?73c27e26f610eb3c9f3feb0c75b03925";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, s);
    })();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Header</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Some Text..</p>
    <a href="#">A Standard Text Link</a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn">Link Button</a>
    <p>A List View:</p>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    </ul>
    <label for="fullname">Input Field:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Name..">    
    <label for="switch">Toggle Switch:</label>
    <select name="switch" id="switch" data-role="slider">
    <option value="on">On</option>
    <option value="off" selected>Off</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Page Footer</h1>
    </div>
    </div> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

The screen shot below shows the view from browser on my computer;

[image]

The screen shot below shows the browser view on my android device; running android version 7;

[image]

I am using phonegap online build to create the app which is downloaded to the android device. I can not see why this is not rendering the same in the android device. I am using the same browser in each, chrome. 
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved this. I was uploading just the index.html to the online phone gap build service.I now have included the other files that phonegap uses when linking to a local device. This has fixed the problem. I thought these would have been added automatically by the online build site. See screen shot below of app on phone.

[image: App on phone]